# Is Digital library website or system?

Tags: user-interface, system, usability, human-computer-interface, user-testing

I am working now on a usability evaluation for digital library and I want to ask is an academic digital library considering educational website or information retrieval system ? in another word, is the library (website or system)? and what is the difference between them ? because I read some literature review menthioned that the digital/online library considering as a system but other said it is an academic website?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: plz clarify your answer, I am a new in this forum

Comment: my question not related to programming , it is just about the correct category for digital library

Comment: Stackoverflow is a forum for questions & answers about specific programming problems, or software tools and algorithms. Please review this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a list of on-topic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a web application. Based on the tags used, I guess it's evaluated from HCI/design perspectives. You should be able to find/use heuristic guidelines on webpage design. In addition, you need to evaluate user interactions, such as how usable it is for a user to search for something, set filters, etc.

Comment: Thanks..I know how can I evaluate the digital library BUT what I want to know in the field of HCI the library evaluating under website or under interactive information retrival system?

Comment: DL can be a website or information retrival system, the major part is it should be able to store any type of data and provide services around the content